# Use PHP to change contents of an element

Tags: php, html, dom

For my login page, currently if the password is incorrect I have to redirect to another page. Is there any way I just insert or show the error message that shows up on the error page on the regular login page using PHP, thus eliminating the need for an error page? i could easily do it with jQuery (`$("#error").css("visibility","visible");`, but I don't know how to interact with the DOM using PHP, because it's executed on the server.

Comment: Use an [HTML Parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: You need a combination of PHP & javascript, can't do anything client-side with PHP. See Rasmus' quick tutorial: http://news.php.net/php.general/219164

Comment: You said it yourself. Php is executed server side. Once it serves up the page, php is done. Javascript is for interacting with the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make all the Javascript(including Jquery) and HTML work using PHP by simply echoing the data. For example:

```
<?php
echo "<script>$('#error').css('visibility','visible');</script>
?>
```

Remember using Single quotes in the Javascript so as not to clash with double-quotes of echo function of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to hide/show elements if I understand your issue correctly. You just echo out an error message when there are an error. Something like:

```
<?php
$showErr = false;
if ($err == true) {
    $showErr = true;
}

//Put this part in code where you want content of the #error to be displayed
if ($showErr == true) {
    echo '<div id="error">ERROR MESSAGE HERE</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Please comment WHY downvote so we can defend ourselves :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the error message needs to be generated in PHP, you may want to consider using AJAX. It is a JavaScript method for getting data from the server and doing something with it in client-side code, without changing the page of the web browser. However, it gets a bit more complicated to do it right, and doing it wrong will just make everything slower and buggier.

The idea would be to use an AJAX request (such as [jQuery's ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) to submit the form data to a specially crafted link which returns a fragment parseable in JavaScript instead of an entire web page. That fragment would tell the client whether the log in was successful or not. If successful, the fragment should contain login credentials which the JavaScript callback should use to set any session cookies and redirect to whatever page you should end up on. If not successful, the fragment should contain the error message which the callback should display to the client. The JavaScript handling the AJAX request must also account for any transmission errors and it should provide feedback to the user that the form was in fact submitted; these things are provided by the browser with normal form submission but not with AJAX requests.